# fuzzy matching japanese strings in python?

Tags: python-2.7

this problem has me stumped for the whole day.

I have two Japanese strings that I want to fuzzy match in Python2.7. Currently I'm using fuzzywuzzy and

```
jpnStr = "日本語".encode('utf-8')
jpnList = ["日本語1".encode('utf-8'),"日本語2".encode('utf-8'),"日本語3".encode('utf-8')]
bestmatch = process.extractOne(jpnStr, jpnList)
```

but the resulting bestmatch is always

```
("日本語1",0)
```

How would I go by resolving this issue, or is there a best practice that I'm totally missing here? Sorry if I sound frustrated, it's been a roadblock for a while. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're passing it UTF-8 bytestrings instead of text?

Comment: In truth I'm not sure. It used to give me "'ascii' not in range error", so I've began encoding everything in UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure how helpful this is but I've found a workaround.

I found that I could fuzzymatch japanese strings using fuzzywuzzy.

1. First, you get the Unicoded Japanese string, ie "日本語です"
2. Then you output it as ascii text into a text file. Output will look something like "/uf34/ufeac/uewa3/..." so on and so forth.
3. Then you read the text file and compare the ascii representation of the japanese string : "/uf34/ufeac/uewa3/" against each other. This gives a workable fuzzywuzzy match rating.

It's probably not an ideal method, but it works and is fairly accurate. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: i found this helpful. @jaimeT do you have any suggestion of any ML model to match keyword?